# Using same click function for multiple elements (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi Im having troubles with getting the following to work. Only the first element works, how should I think?

```
<div class="hi">
    <a id="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>
<div class="hi">
    <a id="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>
<div class="hi">
    <a id="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#tabBtn').on("click",function(){
        if ($(this).parent('.hi').css('max-height') == '65px'){
            $(this).parent(".hi").addClass('open');
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent(".hi").removeClass('open');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you can't use same id's for multiple elements

Comment: use `class` instead of `id` for `tabBtn`

Answer (score 3):

Using the same `id` on multiple elements is invalid, use a `class` instead:

```js
    $('.tabBtn').on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).parent('.job').css('max-height') == '65px') {
        $(this).parent(".job").addClass('open');
      } else {
        $(this).parent(".job").removeClass('open');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hi">
  <a class="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello</a>
</div>
<div class="hi">
  <a class="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello2</a>
</div>
<div class="hi">
  <a class="tabBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Hello3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first thing first `id` attribute should be **ONCE** per page

having say that all you need to do is work on the `on` function from the `document` and in a selecter way like so

```
$(document).on("click",".tabBtn",function(){
  //do work
})
```